# Is it possible to display the fields of the lead after converting

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

I have a vf page on my custom object top panel as custom console component.This object has a lookup relationship with the lead object. So once the lead got converted, will it be possible to display the information of the lead in the top panel of the associated custom object record.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just because the lead is converted doesn't mean it disappears from the database. You can still query for it, it will still appear in lookup fields, and so on. In fact, your code doesn't even need to be concerned as to whether or not it's been converted at all; from its perspective, it's still the same query with the same data.

Comment: @Ram451 addenda -- just don't put a link to the standard Lead detail page in the custom object VF page because if the user clicks it, the Lead will display with a notification message stating it is converted.